# TPT - How to query appropriate child when an instance of base class is selected?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, table-per-type

I'm attempting to determine if my current design using a Table-Per-Type hierarchy is the best way for me to go about the following:

For example, I have 3 child classes (Manager, Executive, Employee) that all inherit from my base Person.  I then would like to display all instances of Person inside a grid view for end-users to select and then edit their associated data.  However, my question pertains to how to query the appropriate type when a Person is selected.  What I'm currently doing is something like the following for the Person class:

```
public class Person 
{
    Guid PersonID { get; set; }    
    string FirstName { get; set; } 
    string LastName { get; set; }   
    string PersonType { get; set; } 
}
```

I then set the `PersonType` field in each of the child classes when they're instantiated.

Set up binding and wire delegate to the `SelectionChanged` event

```
BindingSource peopleBinding = new BindingSource();  
peopleBinding.DataSource = db.People.Local.ToBindingList();
this.peopleGridView.DataSource = peopleBinding;    
this.peopleGridView.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(peopleGridView_SelectionChanged);
```

The GridView's SelectionChanged Event

```
if (peopleGridView.SelectedRows.Count != 1) 
{
     return;
}

Person person = peopleBinding.Current as Person;
if (person == null) 
{ 
     return;
}

switch (person.PersonType) 
{
    case "Employee":         
       Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(person.PersonID);
       // Do Work With Employee
       break;
    case "Manager":
       Manager manager = db.Managers.Find(person.PersonID);
       // Do Work With Manager
       break;
    case "Executive":
       Executive executive = db.Executives.Find(person.PersonID);
       // Do Work With Executive
       break;
    default: 
       throw new ArgumentException (string.Format("Invalid type of person encountered ({0})", person.PersonType);
}
```

Is there a better way to get an instance of the child class rather than using the `PersonType` field as some sort of discriminator in determining what `DbSet` I need to query to get the associated entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
if (person is Employee)
  ...
else if (person is Manager)
  ...
else if (person is Executive)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I had forgotten about the "is" keyword and originally was afraid explicitly down-casting would omit values from the child classes properties.  But taking a look at LinqPad I see that the SQL generated from querying a single ID of the base class includes a join to all the child class takes and looks to bring all the properties into memory for you.   Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If you have (for example) `DbSet<Person>` you can just call `OfType<> on it. Something like:

```
Person person = db.People.OfType<Manager>().Find(PersonID);
```

**Edit:**
In a TPT solution this would also remove the need to store the PersonType Discriminator assuming you do not need it elsewhere.

Comment: Correct; but this is assuming that I knew the selected record was of type "Manager".  Also, this would return an instance of person and I'd like to return the child instance.  My question really pertained to the best way to determine the type of the "Person" that I was dealing with and then the best way to obtain the child instance after finding out what type I was working with.  Running a few quick tests using Sani's suggestion, it looks like that I'm able to explicitly downcast after I find out the type I need to work with.

Comment: The `is` keyword is not operating on your PersonType though, so you can still drop that if not needed.

Comment: Also - in a TPT design, you are loading the 'child' type either way, and I would expect your Person class to be abstract? - I think @Sani was recommending the same thing. your if statements after loading person could be: `if (person is Manager) { Manager manager = (Manager) person; }`